# Ternary Relationship in an ERD: What would the cardinalities look like in this situation?

Tags: database-design, erd

There are four entity types in the business domain of relevance:
**USER**, **COURSE**, **MODULE** and **TOPIC**.

The business rules go something like this:

- A **Course** contains one or more **Modules**, and
- each **Module** contains one or more **Topics**.

So, I have drawn the following entity-relationship diagram (ERD):

[image: How to ERD looks for this bit]

Now,

- a **User** can *study* many **Courses**, and
- a **Course** can *be* *taken* *by* many **Users**.

I want to maintain the progress of a user in that course and so I'm storing an instance of **Topic** in the *studies* relationship.

**Relational representation**

My Relational Table looks like this:

[image: Relational Table Schema]

The `topic_id` column in this table stands for the Next topic the user needs to complete. So whenever the user enrolls for a course I fetch the first topic of the first module of the course and update the row. So `(user_id, course_id)` becomes my composite primary key. Also, when a user completes a topic, I fetch the next topic in the list and update the instance.

**The question**

How do I represent relationship in the ERD with the constraints mentioned above?

[image: Possible Representation]

Since there are three participating entity types, does this make this a ternary relationship, and, if so, what should the cardinalities be like?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat unintuitively you should **drop the reference** to `course` and just leave the references to `user` and `topic` in the `Undergoing` table. To answer directly your question: there should be only two participating entities so it is not a ternary relationship.

This is one of those interesting cases in normalization where **Third normal form (3NF)** is fulfilled but **Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF)** is not. Both are desirable forms in normal database formalization. What breaks the BCNF is the dependency `topic_id`->`course_id`. In plain English: if you know the `topic_id` you can deduce the `course_id` also so you don't need an explicit reference.

When you have `user_topics` relation with references only to `user_id` and `topic_id` you can easily fetch the courses of a user with a regular `JOIN` (via module to course).

Here is more formally put the dependency that is allowed in 3NF but not in BCNF ([Third normal form - Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form):

> Every element of A-X, the set difference between A and X, is a prime attribute (i.e., each attribute in A-X is contained in some candidate key)

[Boyce–Codd normal form (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form):

> Only in rare cases does a 3NF table not meet the requirements of BCNF. A 3NF table which does not have multiple overlapping candidate keys is guaranteed to be in BCNF. Depending on what its functional dependencies are, a 3NF table with two or more overlapping candidate keys may or may not be in BCNF.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer but since I don't have enough reputation so I'd simply like to thank you for your answer.
Although it did seem a bit unintuitive at first, I got what you were trying to say eventually. This has helped majorly..